# Ударение в слове "занята"

Tags: орфоэпия

Всегда ли надо делать ударение в слове *занята* на последний слог? Насчёт одушевлённых предметов вроде очевидно, что да. А как обстоит дело с неодушевлёнными?

На этот вопрос "[Грамота](http://gramota.ru)" мне [ответила](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=280602) в январе этого года, что ударение всегда на последний слог. Однако я по-прежнему сомневаюсь, что она права. Не всегда язык поворачивается так сказать, особенно в выражении "что-то (ж. р.) занято (в примере будет *занята*) чем-то".

Comment: "по - прежнему" сомневаюсь... Извините, Артём, но "по - прежнему"  в данном тексте - наречие, пишется через дефис, потому что есть приставка ПО и суффикс ЕМУ.

Comment: Разумеется, не нужно объяснять.) Спасибо, что сказали, описался!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамота.ру абсолютно права. Сегодня нормой является ударение на окончании. Об этом свидетельствуют словари. В русском языке ударение в ж. р. обычно падает на окончание.

[Вот что говорится в справочнике по правописанию  произношению, литературному редактированию](http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/70091314.html). Глаголы ***снять, заня́ть*** имеют следующие формы ударений: снял, сняла́, сня́ло, сня́ли, сня́в(ши), сня́тый, снят, снята́, сня́то, сня́ты; за́нял, заняла́, за́няло, за́няли, заня́вший, заня́в, за́нятый, за́нят, занята́, за́нято, за́няты и т. д.

Comment: Хм, да. Проверил, оказалось так же и в словах принят**а**, и отнят**а**!

Comment: Да, Артем. Существует определенная закономерность в ударении глаголов. В справочнике подробно об всем говорится.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно нормам акцентологии русского языка, в слове занят**а** ударным является окончание, а в форме глагола прошедшего времени множественного числа з**а**няли - гласный а первого слога.

От глагола занять образуется полная форма страдательного причастия прошедшего времени - з**а**нятый. В свою очередь  причастие имеет краткие формы мужского, среднего, женского рода и множественного числа:

з**а**нятый - з**а**нят, занят**а**, з**а**нято, з**а**няты.

Как видим, во всех кратких формах  причастия ударным является первый гласный *а*, кроме формы женского рода с ударным окончанием.

Правильно скажем: он з**а**нят, место з**а**нято, все з**а**няты, но она занят**а**.

Сейчас появляется разговорная тенденция постановки ударения по смыслу: занятА - активная форма, зАнята - пассивная.

например: 
- секретарша занятА бумагами 
- каюта зАнята туристами

Но это только тенденция, притом разговорная, как норма нигде не закреплена.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! "***Сейчас появляется*** разговорная тенденция..." Неужели в середине прошлого века все говорили "занятА" и в пассивной форме?

Comment: Людмила,как не закреплена? Занят***а*** закреплена словарями. А вот з***а***нята нигде не закреплена. ударение не меняется от одушевленности-неодушевленности.

Comment: Об этом и говорю: закреплено занятА -  зАнята - только  разговорная тенденция

Comment: Артём, речь не идёт о том, все ли говорили, но норма была и есть именно занятА. Другое дело, что разговорная речь иногда может влиять на норму, как, например,огородили место, а там ходить более удобно, там была тропинка, так вот сколько ни огораживай, и не перекапывай, народ будет ходить по той старой тропинке, легче узаконить это, чем запретить. Кофе вот по этому принципу стало допускать форму среднего рода, а как долго пытались приучить к мужскому.!!! Но если войдёт зАнята, это будет исключением из общего правила, вряд ли это будет

Comment: Всё ясно, спасибо! Жаль, что не приучили многих к мужскому роду слова *кофе*.

Comment: Если кофе хороший, он всегда мужского рода, а если плохой, то какая разница?

Answer (score 2):

Мы зАняты работой - все места уже зАняты.Смысл разный, форма одинаковая, но это воспринимается как норма. Аналогично: она занятА - комната занятА.

Разное же значение связано с тем, что **занять (заполнить) можно: а) время; б) пространство.**

Так что нет особого смысла различать эти формы в женском роде, если  остальных случаях они будут совпадать.

Правильность ударения можно проверить **в стихотворных текстах**:

Алина гордая - столицы украшенье;
Увы! окружена ласкателей толпой,
За лесть их отдала любви боготворенье,
За пышный злата блеск - душистые цветы;
Свирели тихий звук Алину не прельщает;
Алина предпочла блаженству суеты;
Собою **занята**, меня в лицо не знает.

*В. Жуковский*

Нынче бабушка Устина важным делом **занята.** Хворостинкой, хворостинкой 
хлещет рыжего кота (автор, к сожалению, неизвестен).

Comment: Значит, "грамота" неправа?

Comment: Почему неправа: она занятА - комната занятА, ударение всегда  на последнем слоге.

Comment: А первое предложение у Вас не по норме, значит? То есть Вы хотите сказать, что так можно было бы говорить, но не стоит?

Comment: В форме мн.числа ударение падает на первый слог: мы зАняты работой - все места уже зАняты.

Comment: Ой, простите, Вера, не заметил, что там **множественное число**!