# Верно ли я запомнила - о "подвижном" ударении: зАнята - занятА?

Tags: орфоэпия

Слышала такое - лет с полсотни тому... по Всесоюзному же радио. Подвижность ударения объяснялась смысловым нюансом.

"Я занят**а** поиском кастрюли, а кастрюля з**а**нята вчерашним супом" (к примеру).

Comment: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418536/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0[Ударение в слове “занята”

Comment: Я знаю, где современные словари делают ударение. Я спрашиваю, помнит ли кто о таком языковом нюансе? Возможно, "устар.", но не примерещилось же!

Comment: Галина, в орфографическом словаре 1963 г. то же самое ударение. Если такое ударение и было, то, наверняка, до 1956г.

Comment: Всесоюзное радио или газеты примером грамотности никогда не были. Хотя бы этот казус из-за опечатки: https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/48546-kak-pravilno-ilichom-ili-ilichem/

Comment: Свифтик, не лукавь! ))) Всесоюзное радио (как и газеты, в "Правде" было 12 корректур!) - это жесточайшая дрессура дикторов. А передача была не с "гостем", который мог оговориться, а посвящённая проблемам ВМПС им. Тургенева.

Comment: Ильдар Ахметов, а пояснения к вопросу не помогают развеять сомнения: дубликат - не дубликат? Зачем мне, редактору, ссылки на интернетные словари?